# Detect if video has no audio in C++, preferable using Qt Phonon

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am creating a video player if Phonon and Qt. everything is working fine, but when I have a video in my playlist that does not have audio I wish to play another audio.
how can I do that? I mean, how can I detect that the video has no audio?

EDIT: By no audio I meant "no audio channel"

Comment: You mean "no audio channel" or also "an audio channel that contains silence"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 5 might help you out. Check out [Phonon::Gstreamer::MediaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/phonon-gstreamer-mediaobject.html). The API is similar to the ordinary MediaObject, but with some additional functions. The one you want is `audioAvailable()`.

Comment: good answer but isnt Qt5 still on alpha version? and isnt the GStreaner the backend only for Linux? My application has to run also in windows...

Comment: @fredcrs Yes, it's in alpha, but beta is scheduled for release quite soon, and the full version soon after. However, I've seen this class in the 4.8.1 source, so it might actually work there too. While browsing through the source, I saw some comments like "FIX ME: MediaObject does not yet have a hasAudio() function", so I guess it should get done soon. That's why I suggested the GStreamer version. And yes, GStreamer does work on Windows, Mac, and Linux.